# Inexact float division

Tags: c, operation

I were practicing some c programming when I saw this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
printf("result %.50lf",(double)10.0/10000000.0);
return 0;
}
```

And the result was 0.00000099999999999999995474811182588625868561393872

Can somebody explain me why happens this?

Comment: Oh no, it's that time of the month again.. http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples

Comment: Even Wikipedia offers [some explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) on this.

Comment: Also Sunday, ie. assignments from a week ago are due tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The internal representation of `double` is a *binary floating-point* encoding that cannot precisely represent all (or indeed most) decimal fractions, for the same reason for example 1/3 cannot be exactly represented in decimal, 10.0/10000000.0 cannot be exactly represented in binary.

Moreover 64-bit double precision binary floating point has a precision of around 15 decimal *significant figures* so attempting to output 50 decimal places is always going to end up in irrelevant and meaningless digits.  Your actual result within the precision of a double is 0.000000999999999999999.

See also: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)